# magento enterprise catalog category permission not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.13

I have setup category permission for my 1 customer group on apparel category.  But it is not working properly.  It is showing apparel category for restricted and guest user in menu and when I click on it, it goes to no-route page. According to standard magento enterprise feature it does not show restricted category to non permissible user group.
I did not override anything regarding catalog menu all default functions are working.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: as it is enterprise edition, contact magento team now only

Comment: As I am developer I can not ask my client for this so I have solve it . please help me

Comment: please post here, so you maty get solution soon : http://magento.stackexchange.com